# How to mark decades and centuries up using HTML5 <time> tag?

Tags: html5, markup

This is how I would mark year 1971 up:

`<time>1971</time>`

`<time datetime="1971">nineteen seventy-one</time>`

But how do I mark a decade **'70s** up (there are also other ways of writing this, like seventies, 1970s, 70s, 1961-1970)?

Also, how do I mark **20th century** up (1901-2000) using HTML5  tag?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The `<time>` tag is not meant to be used for time periods such as decades or centuries.  You should not use it to mark up `'70s` or `20th century`.

The documentation for the tag is [here](https://www.w3.org/TR/2012/WD-html-markup-20120329/time.html).  It says that it can represent:

> - a date
> - a time
> - a date and time

The machine readable representation of those dates and/or times is based on [rfc3339](https://datatracker.ietf.org/doc/html/rfc3339) which states in the introduction:

> Date and time expressions indicate an instant in time. Description of time periods, or intervals, is not covered here.

You could use *two* tags to cover the start and end of the period.  For Example you could mark up `1961-1970` as `<time datetime="1961">1961</time>-<time datetime="1970">1970</time>`.   However when you use a phrase that covers the time period without mentioning its start and end times, it would not be appropriate to use one or more time tags.